# Ubuntu 13.10 vs 14.04 for a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I just picked up a [Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/yoga/yoga-2-pro/) laptop today and want to install Ubuntu on it. I intend to dual boot for the moment with Windows 8.1 and will try to maintain the secure boot setup. As some of you probably already know the laptop is cutting edge with features such as a 3200 x 1800 screen resolution, backlit screen and touchscreen, and a "laptop to tablet folding behavior" which has created an endless number of issues for early adopters wishing to install Ubuntu or other Linux distros on it.

I normally never install alpha software on a machine but was thinking about it on this machine since the newer kernel and modules may allow better handling of cutting edge hardware. I realize that I will be installing alpha software and will avoid doing any mission critical work on the machine. I will also maintain a separate home partition in case I need to downgrade the install or rescue user data.

So 14.04 or 13.10 for this machine?

Comment: I think you answered yourself...

Comment: If you're developing for Ubuntu, 14.04 is recommended. Otherwise, you should use 13.10 to save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, 14.04 is not a stable release.  If you don't want to deal with bugs as much, you should use 13.10 and not 14.04.  When 14.04 is released you can consider using it, though.

The only time you would use 14.04 is if you're planning to do Ubuntu development work in the latest release, or to fix bugs in 14.04.